# C++ and virtual methods overriding

Tags: c++, qt

Sorry for this stupid question, but I can't find an answer by myself, I'm too new in C++ :(

```
class DBObject : public QObject
{
    ...
protected:
    virtual QString tableName() = 0;
};

class DBUserObject : public DBObject
{
    ...
protected:
    virtual QString tableName()  { return "profiles"; };
};
```

And I have this code in parent:

```
DBObject::DBObject(quint32 id)
    : QObject(0)
{
    ...    

    if (id != 0)
        load(id);
}

bool DBObject::load(quint32 id)
{
    QString query = QString("select %1 from %2 where id = :id")
        .arg(fieldList().join(","))
        .arg(tableName());              <--- here is trouble
    ...
}
```

So I'm trying to execute:

```
DBUserObject user(3);
```

But in result I have a runtime error. Why not "profiles"?

Comment: What compiler you are using, on what platform? Does the result change if you move the implementations of `tableName()` into the cpp file, as you did with `load()` ?

Comment: 1. gcc on linux and mingw on windows

2. doesn't change

Comment: Are you _really_ doing just the two lines `DBUserObject user;` followed by `user.load(3);`?

Comment: DBUserObject user(3). It is loading item in its constructor.

Comment: Let me guess: `load()` is being called from the `DBObject` constructor, not the `DBUserObject` constructor?

Comment: See, this is why it's important to post the actual code that's causing the issue, and not something that you think is equivalent. :) Read my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the OP's followup comment:

> DBUserObject user(3). It is loading
>   item in its constructor.

If you mean the `DBObject` constructor (and not the `DBUserObject` constructor), then there's your problem. Virtual functions do not work inside constructors. Constructors run from the least-derived (most base) class to the most-derived (actual type) class. When a class' constructor runs, the object is only of that class' type, and nothing more derived.

In other words, when you create a `DBUserObject`, first the `QObject` constructor runs, and inside that constructor the object is only a `QObect` and nothing more. Then, the `DBObject` constructor runs, and inside that constructor the object is only a `DBObject` and nothing more. Finally, the `DBUserObject` constructor runs and the object is finally a `DBUserObject`.

So if you call `load()` inside of the `DBObject` constructor, the object is only a `DBObject` at that point and so has only the `DBObject` version of load. This applies similarly for any virtual function.

If you want to get the effect of calling the `DBUserObject` version of `load()`, you will need to call it from the `DBUserObject` constructor, or from outside the class after the object has been constructed.

More information:

- http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#vcall
- http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

Comment: Wow. It works, thank you for you help and patience.
Sorry for all, I didn't expected that problem cause of constructor use :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most probably not in the code you provided. Are you slicing the `DBObject`s? That could happen if you pass by value into a function, or if you store inside a container directly (not through a pointer).

Another thing is why is the `tableName()` not pure-virtual in your base class?

Comment: What is pure-virtual function? Sorry again - I'm too new in C++

Comment: @silent: Pure virtual means that the function does not define a body. This makes the class "abstract" (although this is not a C++ keyword). What it means is, that the class cannot be instantiated, it merely serves as a template from which other classes will be derived, which will then provide a body for the pure virtual function. It is defined like this: virtual void func() = 0;

Answer (score 2):

you could use a 'pure virtual' function to make sure that only subclasses can be used, since the base class (DbObject) doesn't have a table name.

this would force all instantiations of DbObject (through the inherited classes) to have a *valid* table name

example:
`virtual QString tableName() = 0;`

Comment: Then your problem is that you are not actually overriding the `tableName` function in the `DBUserObject` class. Are you *sure* that what you posted above is an exact reflection of your code? Make sure that you did not misspell `tableName` or add a `const` qualifier, or change the return type, or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 1):

First, use Google to read about "object slicing" in C++. It's easy (but wrong) to slice an object in C++, especially for novices: slicing happens if you pass an object by value (which is usually wrong) instead of passing by reference (which is usually right), for example if you declare a parameter of type "DBObject" (wrong) instead of "DbObject&" or "const DbObject&" (right).

Second, add the following statements to your DBObject class:

```
class DBObject : public QObject 
{ 
    ... 
protected: 
    virtual QString tableName()  { return ""; }; 
private:
    //non-default, unimplemented copy ctor and assignment operator
    DBObject(const DBObject&);
    DBObject& operator=(const DBObject&);
};
```

Declaring non-default, unimplemented copy and assignment will cause compile-time errors whereveryou try to pass a DBObject by value: so, the third step is to fix these errors by changing the parameter types to pass by reference instead.

Comment: Thank you for slicing and references, I'll check it today

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't inline virtual functions, because some compilers can't handle that very well.

You should move the implementation of DBObject::tableName() and DBUserObject::tableName to the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be doing anything wrong here. Are you sure the problem is not with your QString::arg(...) method?

Explicitly call this->tableName(); looks like a compiler problem.

-- UPDATE --

Actually your definition of tableName() should be

```
virtual void tableName() const { ... }
```

Make sure that your operator= for QString is in order (both a const and non-const version), it could be that the QString that is returned from tableName() is a temporary via the stack, in which case the operator= will be called...

Comment: Tried to do just QString tb = tableName() - the same empty string.

Comment: make sure that the base and derived are defined by const otherwise the dervived does not override the base. I think that you need to look at the QString class.